# Insert into table using common table express result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm practicing SQL and trying to get the last record and add a new record that's incrementing the year and id. I know this can be done easier but I'm trying to get the ideas of how to use CTE. Thank you in advance.

I'm getting a syntax error. using MySQL 8.0

```
WITH cte_0 (id,first_name,last_name,age,date_of_age) as (
select * from sales order by age desc limit 1
), 
cte_1 (id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age) as (
select id + 1 as id,first_name,last_name,age +1 as age, DATE_ADD(date_of_age ,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) as data_of_age from cte_0
)
insert into sales (id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age) select id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age from cte_1
;
```

SYNTAX ERROR:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into sales (id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age) select id,first_name' at line 7    0.000 sec

Comment: Any particular reason for not sharing the exact error message, so that we do not have to guess where it occurs?

Comment: When you ask for help with a syntax error, please post the exact and full error message. Don't make us guess!

Comment: Good point, I have updated the questions with the syntax error code. Thanks for the quick reply. Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into sales (id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age) select id,first_name' at line 7 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the CTEs inside the INSERT statement:

```
insert into sales (id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age)
WITH cte_0 (id,first_name,last_name,age,date_of_age) as (
select * from sales order by age desc limit 1
), 
cte_1 (id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age) as (
select id + 1 as id,first_name,last_name,age +1 as age, DATE_ADD(date_of_age ,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) as data_of_age from cte_0
) 
select id,first_name,last_name,age,data_of_age from cte_1;
```

Comment: Oh, I see thank you very much. New at SQL so I figured there was something I wasn't understanding.